# str.find == -1 but the string cant pass the if condition

Tags: python, string, if-statement

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=utf-8
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
import json
import requests
from chardet import detect

false = False
null = ""
true = True
#from werobot import client
file_path = 'data1.json'
with open(file_path) as f:
    js = f.read()

dic = eval(js)



def ana(month):
    i = len(dic["items"])-1
    st = ""
    while i > 0:
        #print dic["items"][i]["name"]

        if st.find(dic["items"][i]["name"]) == -1:
            #print st.find(dic["items"][194]["name"])

            st = st + dic["items"][i]["properties"]["lastModifiedDate"][0:4].replace("/",".")+" " + dic["items"][i]["name"] +str(i)+"\n"
            i = i - 1
        i = i - 1

    return st 
all_data = ana("7")

print all_data
```

> st.find(dic["items"][194]["name"]) = -1

but it can't pass the if condition:

> st.find(dic["items"][i]["name"]) == -1

data1.json is on the gist: [data1.json on gist](https://gist.github.com/relei1988/60f14af49e16ea1638709b7530bc212f)

Is there anything wrong with this codes?

Comment: Use `json.load` to load json data, not `eval`.

Comment: sorry,it's a dict,not a json file

Comment: Please reformat your lines to 80 characters or less, so the actual if-statement is readable without scrolling and losing sight of the rest of the code.

Comment: Have you excluded the possibility that any of the other clauses in the if-statement fail? The `str.find` is only one of the many clauses in that if-statement; any of them could fail.

Comment: The format seems to be JSON and it's call data1. **json**. How could it be a dict?

Comment: @9769953 yep,I tried remove this statement,then dic["items"][194]["name"]) can be added in st

Comment: @KlausD.sorry,it's renamed by myself,I thought it's a json file,but it's a dict,and can't use json.load func

Comment: @9769953 I've reformat the long if-statement,thanks

Comment: It is not a dict. It might be a text file containing a Python dict literal, but it isn't a dict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're decrementing `i` twice: once inside the if-statement, once every time in the `while` loop. Hence, when the if statement evaluates to `True`, `i` will be decremented by `2` in total, and you will skip past some values of `i`.

A quick test shows that, indeed, `i == 194` is skipped: `i` jumps from `195` to `193`. Thus, the particular comparison you mention is never evaluated, because `i` is never `194`.

This is easy to evaluate and debug yourself: just use `print(i)` in every loop, just before the if-statement, and see how it changes.

---

In addition, you state your input is a dict. It is, in fact, a perfectly valid JSON file, and you can (should) read it as follows:

```
import json

with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    dic = json.load(f)
```

No need to use `eval`, no need to use `false = False; null = ""; true = True`. These lines can only create confusion and (severe) bugs, and should be removed. Note, by the way, that `null` (JSON) is transformed to `None` in Python, not `""` (the empty string).

Comment: thanks a lot ,it was a stupid question indeed.I was confused.

Comment: I'll try json.load(f),days ago I tried this func,but it raises exception

Comment: @chenjunjie I had no problem; possibly because I'm using Python 3, and you seem to be using Python 2. In that case, the [`encoding` parameter of `json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load) may be of help, though the default appears to be UTF-8 already. Possibly add an encoding for `with open(...)` as well, or try reading as binary instead. Alternatively (and preferably), switch to Python 3.

Comment: thanks a lot for ur help,the error message shows"ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded",I'm using python 2.7.3